# Datasets with pre- and post migration earnings

Tags: data-request, migration

I am interested in computing the pre- and post-migration earnings of international migrants, especially those migrating from low income to high income countries (or vice versa).
The data should allow me to compute pre- and post-migration earnings for each individual (as opposed to having one group with earnings at home and another with earnings abroad).
I am aware of:

- New Immigrant Survey
- Latin American Migration Project (LAMP and MMP)
- Migrating out of poverty
- data used in some small scale studies for one country (e.g. Tonga)

Could anyone point out additional data sources?